# I Want to receive a mail from a particular location

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mailer

Here is my Code
http://codepad.org/NHykpcrq

I have given each location a separate id. I want a mail to let me know that i received from that Location.

Comment: do you get any error ? what is the question ?

Answer (score 0):

You can just assign a value in your if statements (you might want to change this to a switch statement)

```
if ($host == 'locahost/dribblefootball/calendar_new/calendar.php?id=1') {
    $to = 'tanmay.kamath1992@gmail.com';
    $location = 'Some Name for this thing';
} elseif ($host == 'locahost/dribblefootball/calendar_new/calendar.php?id=2') {
    $to = 'tanmay.kamath1992@gmail.com';
    $location = 'Some Name for this thing 2';
} elseif ($host == 'locahost/dribblefootball/calendar_new/calendar.php?id=3') {
    $to = 'tanmay.kamath1992@gmail.com';
    $location = 'Some Name for this thing 3';
} else { //other options
    $to = 'others@mysite.com';
    $location = 'Some Name for this thing else';
}
$formcontent .= '\n Sent from '.$location;
```

There might be a spelling mistake in your localhost thing :), another idé (which makes it portable) is to change the thing your looking for to be something like this:

```
($_GET['id'] === 1)
```

And so on.

**EDIT**

A [switch](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) statement with the 2 changes would look like this

```
switch ($_GET['id']) {
    case 1:
        $to = 'tanmay.kamath1992@gmail.com';
        $location = 'Some Name for this thing';
        break;
    case 2:
        $to = 'tanmay.kamath1992@gmail.com';
        $location = 'Some Name for this thing 2';
        break;
    case 3:
        $to = 'tanmay.kamath1992@gmail.com';
        $location = 'Some Name for this thing 3';
        break;
    default:
        $to = 'others@mysite.com';
        $location = 'Some Name for this thing else';
        break;
}
```

Comment: can you please contact me on my mail id. i am getting a hard time in mailing the location fetched from the url.